# Как подружить Filterrific и default_scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Для фильтрации записей на странице я использую gem Filterrific. В данном примере речь пойдет о фильтрации по дате создания/обновления записи.

Есть такой рабочий код:

```
scope :sorted_by, lambda { |sort_option|
    direction = sort_option =~ /desc$/ ? :desc : :asc

    case sort_option.to_s
    when /^created_at_/
        order(created_at: direction)
    when /^updated_at/
        order(updated_at: direction)
    else
        raise(ArgumentError, "Invalid sort option: #{sort_option.inspect}")
    end
}
```

Но он перестает работать, как только в модель добавляется эта строка:

```
default_scope { order(updated_at: :desc) }
```

То есть с добавлением этой строки теперь абсолютно всегда элементы будут сортироваться только так: `updated_at: :desc`.

Как "подружить" Filterrific и default_scope?

Comment: `default_scope { order(updated_at: :desc) }` вообще-то и означает, что "теперь абсолютно всегда элементы будут сортироваться только так", определитесь уже :D

Comment: Окей, есть `unscoped`, конечно, но если его надо использовать в больших количествах, ставится под сомнение необходимость в `default_scope`.

Comment: @D-side я просто думал, что `default_scope` просто "добавит по умолчанию что-то". В данном случае я думал, что `Post.all` в контроллере будет "по дефолту" как `Post.all.order(created_at: :desc)`. То есть я думал что в дальнейшем этот `default_scope` как бы можно дополнить. Ну, надеюсь я понятно изъяснился :)

Comment: @D-side я тут еще сам поковырялся. Пришел к тому, что `default_scope ` мне и не нужен в данной ситуации, так как с помощью Filterrific можно задать тот "дефолт". Но за информацию об `default_scope` благодарю :)

Comment: @D-side добавлю еще про `unscoped`. Боюсь что в Filterrific это не безопасно, так как может "сбиться" какой-нибудь фильтр, если применять их разом и несколько.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Против `default_scope` есть только [метод `unscoped`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-unscoped).

Но с каждым появлением у вас в коде `unscoped` (начиная с первого же) вас должен всё сильнее и сильнее мучить вопрос: *"Возможно, я что-то делаю не так?"*

Вся суть `default_scope` в том, чтобы какие-то параметры отношения, нужные много где и ненужные мало где (или нигде), указать *один раз* и впоследствии читать, что они "сами собой разумеющиеся". Если вы начинаете пользоваться `unscoped`, то входит, что они не вполне "сами собой разумеющиеся". Конечно, мы живём в реальном мире, где исключения есть из любых простых правил (в т. ч. из этого). Но чем чаще вам приходится это делать,  тем меньше было смысла брать `default_scope` изначально. Поэтому некоторые его избегают вообще. Но и такой подход порой плохо заканчивается.

Часто встречающийся пример, когда это оправдано — "мягкое удаление", при котором объект не удаляется, а лишь отмечается удалённым, а (почти) все запросы содержат условие "не удалён". Но лишь при условии, что в проекте очень мало мест, где с удалёнными объектами можно что-то сделать  (например, один контроллер админки).

У вас скорее наоборот, необходима сортировка по умолчанию ровно в одном месте (где фильтры доступны, когда ни один не активен), поэтому там её и стоит указать. Вам `default_scope` просто не нужен. Вам нужно скорее настроить сам `filterrific`:

```
  filterrific(
    default_filter_params: { sorted_by: 'updated_at_desc' },
    available_filters: [
      # ...
    ]
  )
```

Comment: Как всегда все четко расписали. Спасибо большое :)